# Visual Studo C++ import Office 365 excel.exe - how to exclude unuse attribute that cause troubles

Tags: c++, excel, office365

I'm learning the book "Financial Instrument Pricing Using C++, 2nd Edition" for excel interaction.

My environment: Visual Studio 2017 + Excel Office 365

Following exising discussion, my test code below

```
#include <iostream>
#include "atlsafe.h"
#import "D:\project_CPP\C++_study\instrument_pricing\lib\mso.dll"  rename("DocumentProperties", "DocumentPropertiesXL") rename("RGB", "RGBXL")
#import "D:\project_CPP\C++_study\instrument_pricing\lib\VBE6EXT.OLB" rename("RGB", "RBGXL")
using namespace Office;
#import "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE" rename("DialogBox", "DialogBoxXL") rename("RGB", "RGBXL") rename("DocumentProperties", "DocumentPropertiesXL") rename("ReplaceText", "ReplaceTextXL") rename("CopyFile", "CopyFileXL") exclude ("Ifont","IPicture","ISensitivityLabelPolicy")  no_dual_interfaces no_function_mapping 



int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    system("pause");

}
```

I got below error after try and fail many times.
It seems DataPrivacyOption is a new feature of Office, so I only had error related to those. I dont need to use these and most of excel/attribute, so just want to exclude those

```
1>testExcel.cpp
1>d:\project_cpp\c++_study\testexcel\testexcel\testexcel.cpp(9): warning C4192: automatically excluding 'IFont' while importing type library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE'
1>d:\project_cpp\c++_study\testexcel\testexcel\debug\excel.tlh(7353): error C2039: 'SensitivityLabelPolicyPtr': is not a member of 'Office'
1>d:\project_cpp\c++_study\testexcel\testexcel\debug\mso.tlh(13): note: see declaration of 'Office'
1>d:\project_cpp\c++_study\testexcel\testexcel\debug\excel.tlh(7353): error C3646: 'SensitivityLabelPolicy': unknown override specifier
1>d:\project_cpp\c++_study\testexcel\testexcel\debug\excel.tlh(7353): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>d:\project_cpp\c++_study\testexcel\testexcel\debug\excel.tlh(7759): error C2039: 'DataPrivacyOptionsPtr': is not a member of 'Office'
1>d:\project_cpp\c++_study\testexcel\testexcel\debug\mso.tlh(13): note: see declaration of 'Office'
1>d:\project_cpp\c++_study\testexcel\testexcel\debug\excel.tlh(7759): error C3646: 'DataPrivacyOptions': unknown override specifier
1>d:\project_cpp\c++_study\testexcel\testexcel\debug\excel.tlh(7759): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>d:\project_cpp\c++_study\testexcel\testexcel\debug\excel.tlh(8721): error C2039: 'DataPrivacyOptionsPtr': is not a member of 'Office'
1>d:\project_cpp\c++_study\testexcel\testexcel\debug\mso.tlh(13): note: see declaration of 'Office'
1>d:\project_cpp\c++_study\testexcel\testexcel\debug\excel.tlh(8721): error C3646: 'GetDataPrivacyOptions': unknown override specifier
1>d:\project_cpp\c++_study\testexcel\testexcel\debug\excel.tlh(8721): error C2059: syntax error: '('
1>d:\project_cpp\c++_study\testexcel\testexcel\debug\excel.tlh(8721): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>d:\project_cpp\c++_study\testexcel\testexcel\debug\excel.tlh(8725): error C2039: 'SensitivityLabelPolicyPtr': is not a member of 'Office'
1>d:\project_cpp\c++_study\testexcel\testexcel\debug\mso.tlh(13): note: see declaration of 'Office'
1>d:\project_cpp\c++_study\testexcel\testexcel\debug\excel.tlh(8725): error C3646: 'GetSensitivityLabelPolicy': unknown override specifier
1>d:\project_cpp\c++_study\testexcel\testexcel\debug\excel.tlh(8725): error C2059: syntax error: '('
1>d:\project_cpp\c++_study\testexcel\testexcel\debug\excel.tlh(8725): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>d:\project_cpp\c++_study\testexcel\testexcel\debug\excel.tlh(10565): error C2039: 'ISensitivityLabelPtr': is not a member of 'Office'
1>d:\project_cpp\c++_study\testexcel\testexcel\debug\mso.tlh(13): note: see declaration of 'Office'
1>d:\project_cpp\c++_study\testexcel\testexcel\debug\excel.tlh(10565): error C3646: 'SensitivityLabel': unknown override specifier
1>d:\project_cpp\c++_study\testexcel\testexcel\debug\excel.tlh(10565): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>d:\project_cpp\c++_study\testexcel\testexcel\debug\excel.tlh(11171): error C2039: 'ISensitivityLabelPtr': is not a member of 'Office'
1>d:\project_cpp\c++_study\testexcel\testexcel\debug\mso.tlh(13): note: see declaration of 'Office'
1>d:\project_cpp\c++_study\testexcel\testexcel\debug\excel.tlh(11171): error C3646: 'GetSensitivityLabel': unknown override specifier
1>d:\project_cpp\c++_study\testexcel\testexcel\debug\excel.tlh(11171): error C2059: syntax error: '('
1>d:\project_cpp\c++_study\testexcel\testexcel\debug\excel.tlh(11171): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>d:\project_cpp\c++_study\testexcel\testexcel\debug\excel.tli(4912): error C2039: 'DataPrivacyOptionsPtr': is not a member of 'Office'
1>d:\project_cpp\c++_study\testexcel\testexcel\debug\mso.tlh(13): note: see declaration of 'Office'
1>d:\project_cpp\c++_study\testexcel\testexcel\debug\excel.tli(4912): error C2039: 'GetDataPrivacyOptions': is not a member of 'Excel::_Application'
1>d:\project_cpp\c++_study\testexcel\testexcel\debug\excel.tlh(7264): note: see declaration of 'Excel::_Application'
1>d:\project_cpp\c++_study\testexcel\testexcel\debug\excel.tli(4912): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

I already tried:

```
 ("Ifont","IPicture","ISensitivityLabelPolicy")
```